# How do I get a HingeJoint2D to be rigid instead of elastic?

Tags: physics, unity

I made a chain of 40 segment using a HingeJoint2D. I followed the instructions directly off this [Unity tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEVXE7_YILk)

But when I start the game the chain bounces and stretches and then slowly over about 20 seconds it slowly pulls it self back up

[image: elastic chain]

How do I get the chain to actually be rigid instead of elastic?

If that's impossible, how do I get them to start in a rest state instead of starting with a bounce?

[I uploaded the scene here](http://greggman.com/downloads/chain-example.unitypackage) if you want to play with it in Unity yourself.

Comment: It is impossible, that is the physics engine running and that is how the HInge Joint works.